# IOError: File not open for writing when opening CSV file in universal mode

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to open a csv file in universal mode so that i can view the contents of file during the execution of program because my code has to write round about 80000 records. but at the time of writing row to csv i get the error as "IOError: File not open for writing" . Here is my code:

```
  with open('Output.csv', "U") as f:
       writer=csv.writer(f,delimiter=',', quotechar='"',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
       headingList=['SpID','Family','Genus','Species','Classification','Habit','isImageAvailabe']
       mainclass.writeLine(writer,headingList)

  def writeLine(rowWriter,list):
       rowWriter.writeRow() # at this line i am getting the mentioned error.
```

and i try it to open in "wb" mode then it doesn't allow me to view the contents during the execution.

Comment: `'U'` refers to universal newline - see http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/. What exactly is the problem in `'wb'` mode? The file will be empty at first because `'w'` removes anything already there when the file is opened.

Comment: i want to see the contents of my output.csv file during the execution but when opened in 'wb' mode for writing , it doesn't make me see the contents of output file.

Comment: How about the `wb+` mode? Opens a (blank or overwritten) file with write and read access. See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_files_io.htm for more informations about the file access modes

Comment: Bear in mind that the file pointer will be at the end of whatever you've written, so if you read from there you won't get anything.